# RUBY ON RAILS - "msvcrt-ruby18.dll was not found" with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i am using:
windows 7
rails 3.0

whenever i try to run rake db:migrate. i get the following error in popup...

*This application has failed to start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem.*

need help here..
thnx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of ruby you are using?

If `<= 1.8` then just add that dll to your path (you should have it somewhere).

If, instead, you are using ruby `>= 1.9` then probably one of your gems that you installed has native compnents which haven't been updated for this version and still rely on older ruby dlls. You could try by compiling them natively (it will be hard under Win7) or search for an updated version somewhere.

Comment: this means that one of your gem has been installed as a native binary from the repository and that gem hasn't been updated for 1.9. I had this problem with BlueCloth and I had to switch to RedCloth since no BlueCloth compiled gem was available when I tried and building a native one on Windows is quite crazy (you need something able to compile like Cygwin)

Comment: mind that trying to add the 1.8 dll to get around the problem is not a safe fix for this issue..

Comment: you really should be using the MinGW port of YARV, not the MSVC or Cygwin one, in which case the DevKit makes compiling native extensions completely trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`msvcrt-ruby18.dll` is the runtime library for MRI 1.8.x. Somehow, you installed a MRI C extension for which the author provides a pre-compiled binary, but with the wrong version information. That way, you ended up with a C extension that has been compiled for MRI 1.8.x, but you are actually using YARV 1.9.2-p0.

You need to find either a different version of the gem which provides a pre-compiled binary for your version of YARV, or you need to compile it yourself.

If you use [the MinGW port of YARV](http://RubyInstaller.Org/), that's trivial: just install [the DevKit](https://GitHub.Com/OneClick/RubyInstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) and then re-install the offending gem with the `--platform=ruby` option, to force compilation.

Comment: On Windows such dll missings can be solved just copying dll from another Ruby installs. This method always worked fine in my practice. Maybe on *nix it needs some compilation, but I copied dlls even from XP to Win7. I think, to solve this problem, it's enough just to google where to download dll with this name )

Answer (score 0):

Read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250406/msvcrt-ruby18-dll-was-not-found-with-ruby) if this problem appears on starting the mongrel using "mongrel_rails start"

Install the new pre-release version of Mongrel:

gem install mongrel --pre

Also add "gem mongrel" to your Gemfile and run the application using "rails s"